# How to fix Openstack-Install Juju bootstrap error: must be str, not None

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I try to install a multi-node openstack environment on my ESXi lab.
I commissioned three machines with virsh.

When I start a multi-node install, the installer takes a new VM and starts to deploy it. Right after the deployment, the openstack-installer crashes with the following fatal error: http://pastebin.com/2bUny3yS

How do I fix this error? I started this install from my MAAS-Controller (Ubuntu 14.04).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was addressed @ https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/631

Basically boiled down to not running the installer as a non-root user.

Comment: That was also me ;-)